# Como pegar a data atual menos dois anos no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Preciso mostrar em uma consulta alguns itens entre a data  atual do tempo em questão e dois anos antes.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o `BETWEEN` com [`date_sub`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) para subtrair um intervalo da data informada:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR);
```